# MVC not seeing https web api

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, webapi

C# SSL security certificate wizard needed!

Postman works, SoapUI works, my code gets a 404!

I have created a C# 4.7.2 MVC Web application.  It makes a RestRequest().Post to a C# WebApi hosted on iis.  This all works properly and as expected on http.

Now I want to make it https, I have added a security certificate to iis.  Now I have problems.
If I make the request via Postman or SoapUI I get the response as before no problem.   When I make the call with my C# HelperApp I get a 404 back!  (Of course I checked the address path a thousand times.)
The 404 really confuses things.  It's definitely there and we are hitting it successfully with Postman and SoapUI.

I suspect that I am not telling the RestClient to use SSL?

TIA.

```
                   case "Submit":

                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;  
                    
                    var apiServer = Startup.Config.ApiUrl; // this points to web.config <add key="API_URL" value="https://xxx.yyy.local:444/" />   
                    //It works when I use <add key="API_URL" value="http://IEAVNBQ02:85/" />

                    var baseUrl = apiServer + $"api/ProcessQuotes/";

                    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
                    client.Options.MaxTimeout = -1;
          
                    
                    var request = new RestRequest();
                    request.Method = Method.Post;


                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", model.JsonRequest, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                    var response = client.Execute(request);
```

var Response is populated with:

```
<title>Network Error: 404</title>
<meta name="description" content="Proxy Exception: Network Error: 404" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

before making a call.

Just keep in mind this is a global setting.

Comment: Hello Martron!   I am not sure where to insert the ServicePointManager code.  
I have added code about and a portion of the Response.

Comment: I had a look at your code and it seems to me that you may have forgotten to put '/' in your base url. So instead of apiServer + $"api/ProcessQuotes/" try apiServer + $"/api/ProcessQuotes/"

Comment: baseURL at the breakpoint is "https://xxx.yyy.local:444/api/ProcessQuotes/"   This is an exact character for character copy of what is used in Postman and SoapUI.   I am currently rewriting using HttpClient() or whatever else I can try :/

Comment: Note: StackOverflow is not liking some of my inserted code too much.  It chopped out displaying "h t t p s: / / " in the previous message

Comment: I don't have a final answer yet.   It looks like the code is ok and the problem is on iis.  I have created calling code in a .dll and used it with a console app, this can call the SSL server just fine, but the same code/.dll used with a web app (both forms and MVC) does not work and returns a 404.   
My Web Apps can call from the test helper sites like h,t,t,p,s/"/httpbin.org".  So I can only conclude at this time that iis is somehow blocking calls from web browsers.  I will let you know :)

Comment: If it doesnt work on the browser it might be down to the SSL certificate itself. Browsers do not allow certificates that dont have "Subject Alternative Name" field specified.

Comment: I still have no solution but hopefully have asked a better targeted question here, because I don't think it's on the C# side.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879777/adding-ssl-cert-causes-404-only-in-browser-calls