# Adding SSL cert causes 404 only in browser calls

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I am working in an internal corporate environment.  We have created a webapi installed on iis on port 85.  We call this from another MVC HelperApp on port 86.  It all works as expected.  Now we want to tighten security and add an SSL cert to iis on port 444 and bind it to our API.

Initially we test it with Postman, SoapUI, and a C# console app and it all works.  Now we try calling it from our MVC HelperApp and it returns a 404 sometimes.

Deeper debugging; I put the code into a C# DLL (see below).  Using the console app I call the Dll.PostAPI and it works as expected.   Now I call that same Dll.PostAPI from the MVC HelperApp and it won't work.  When I step through the code I make it as far as this line  `await client.PostAsync(url, data);`  and the code bizarrely ends, it doesn't return and it doesn't throw an exception.  Same for Post and Get.  I figure it makes the call and nothing is returned, no response and no error.

Also, if I change the url to "https://httpbin.org/post" or to the open http port85 on iss it will work.  I have concluded that the C# code is not the problem (but I'm open to being wrong).

Therefore I have come to the conclusion that for some reason the port or cert is refusing calls from browsers.

We are looking at:

- the "Subject Alternative Name" but all the examples show
- WWW.Addresses which we are not using.
- the "Friendly Name" on the cert creation.
- and CORS Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

These are all subjects we lack knowledge in.

This is the calling code used exactly the same in the console app and the web app:

```
    var lib = new HttpsLibrary.ApiCaller();
    lib.makeHttpsCall();
```

This is what's in the DLL that gets called:

```
    public async Task<string> makeHttpsCall()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote>();

            quotes.Add(CreateDummyQuote());

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quotes);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


            var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";  //this works in Browser
            //url = "https://thepath:444//api/ProcessQuotes"; //444 DOES NOT WORK in browsers only.  OK in console app.
            //url = "http://thepath:85/api/ProcessQuotes";  //85 works.
            

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data); //<<<this line never returns when called from browser.
            //var response = await client.GetAsync(url);  //same outcome for Get or Post
            
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: _"and the code bizarrely ends, it doesn't return and it doesn't throw an exception."_ sounds like you're describing an async deadlock.

Comment: TLS is performed before a request is sent and if TLS fails than you will never get a response (status 404).  Are you using a proxy?  Error 404 is page not found.  I've seen errors like this when going through a proxy.  Does working apps use proxy.  Maybe proxy is set true in your app.

Comment: Your actual HTTPS site binding on IIS determines what is the correct URL to connect from a client, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html If wrong URLs are used, then the client might be dispatched to another site and 404 is not surprising. Note that SNI or not also matters, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings

Comment: @LexLi due to the nature of the infrastructure layout in this company, it's spread out over countries, I'm finding it hard to get a definitive answer about the Proxy.  I don't believe we are using a proxy.   And also to note that calls from other callers, Postman, SoapUI, Console App... all work.

Comment: In your description, you mention that this problem occurs intermittently? Can you get any error log information when this issue occurs? Or does it work to remove and re-add the certificate from browser?

Comment: @XudongPeng the problem is not intermittent.  It absolutely will not work when called from a browser.

Comment: @jdweng I finally got confirmation that the proxy logs are showing my targets being hit.  Now I have to figure out what to do with this information.  Progress is slow because I work across departments across countries.